# What are the pros and cons of using Inorder traversal to check if tree is BST or not?

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree, traversal

I stumble upon many ways to find if a given tree is BST or not, I think inorder way is the best and easy to understand way, but is it really the best way?

**Way 1:**

```
int isBSTUtil(node* node, int min, int max);  
  
/* Returns true if the given  
tree is a binary search tree  
(efficient version). */
int isBST(node* node)  
{  
    return(isBSTUtil(node, INT_MIN, INT_MAX));  
}  
  
/* Returns true if the given 
tree is a BST and its values 
are >= min and <= max. */
int isBSTUtil(node* node, int min, int max)  
{  
    /* an empty tree is BST */
    if (node==NULL)  
        return 1;  
              
    /* false if this node violates 
    the min/max constraint */
    if (node->data < min || node->data > max)  
        return 0;  
      
    /* otherwise check the subtrees recursively,  
    tightening the min or max constraint */
    return
        isBSTUtil(node->left, min, node->data-1) && // Allow only distinct values  
        isBSTUtil(node->right, node->data+1, max); // Allow only distinct values  
}
```

**Way 2(Inorder):**

```
bool isBST(node* root)  
{  
    static node *prev = NULL;  
      
    // traverse the tree in inorder fashion  
    // and keep track of prev node  
    if (root)  
    {  
        if (!isBST(root->left))  
        return false;  
  
        // Allows only distinct valued nodes  
        if (prev != NULL &&  
            root->data <= prev->data)  
        return false;  
  
        prev = root;  
  
        return isBST(root->right);  
    }  
  
    return true;  
}
```

It'll be really helpful if you can point out pros and cons of each way of finding out.

Comment: `INT_MIN, INT_MAX` -- What if some nodes actually has values equal to these?

Comment: You need to clarify your criteria for "best".  There are many you might choose from: short code, fast code, simple code, cache-friendly code, memory-efficient code, parallelizable code, minimal assembly code...

Comment: Testing for `< INT_MIN` or `> INT_MAX` will not work if those constants have the usual values. The business with `prev` isn't too attractive. It would make more sense to pass it around as a parameter.

Comment: Inorder seems best to me too. In terms of clarity of code, you are testing what really matters, that the in order sequence of the nodes is strictly ordered. However you really should change that static `prev` variable into a parameter. Static variables are to be avoided in general.

Comment: `int isBST(node*)` is a weird function signature. Firstly, it returns `int` instead of `bool` for no good reason (C++ is not C), secondly, it takes `node*` instead of `const node*` for no good reason, too.

Comment: @Evg Look at the big picture mate, I mean Inorder seems better than any other way right?